# Flex 4 Datagrid Header

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, header

I have created my own DataGridHeader class - by extending the default DataGridHeader.

In the contructor of this class I have added an event listener to listen to column clicks with the cntrl key pressed.

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
```

It appears though that the keyDownHandler is not being called at all....bizarre...it works just fine when I add the same event listener to the DataGrid class but not the DataGridHeader class.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: are you using a spark or mx datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridHeader` has the following method which you can override:

```
protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void;
```

Then you can refer to the `MouseEvent` documentation [to found `ctrlKey` flag there](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5#ctrlKey).

I think this information is enough to solve your problem :)